# How to store multiple numpy 2d matrices - with different sizes - into one numpy matrix?

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix, structure

In short:
I need to load multiple 2d numpy matrices - with different sizes - into one numpy matrix. First, I tried to load them as the 3rd dimension of the matrix but due to the various sizes it wasn't possible. It would be great if you could direct me how to do it, or even any other convenient solution.

More description:
I'm reading arrays from multiple csv files and loading them into numpy arrays. This is easy when the number of csv files are known and the arrays are at the same size. Whereas, I need to do this for any number of files at different sizes. So I thought I could use numpy's structured arrays, but I can't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Numpy is going to require mathematically consistent matrices... which means all rows/columns in a 2D matrix have to have the same number of elements.  Likewise, if you try to make a 3-dimensional matrix, each 2D matrix will have to have the same dimensions.

However, you *could* use a regular Python array of numpy matrices.  If you do that, then you can dynamically add/remove individual matrices, and they can have varying dimensions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually got the answer to my question (But then how to retrieve the matrices back?)